# C# FilePath Problems WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, filepath

I am trying to output the file address of an item selected in a combobox. But i keep getting the Directory address of the project and not the item itself. Please help. Here is my Code:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (availableSoftDropBox.SelectedItem.Equals("Choose Your Own..."))
        {
            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                txtFlashFile.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;

        }
         else
        {



         string fileName;
         fileName = Path.GetFullPath((string)availableSoftDropBox.SelectedItem);
        string fullPath = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\yeet-n . master\yeet- 
                         master\src\yeet\System\Products\" + (fileName);


         txtFlashFile.Text = fullPath;
```

Comment: What's a file or directory address? Like a path?

Comment: I meant the FilePath of the item selected

Comment: I don't really understand what you're saying. Are you saying the open file dialog never even opens?

Comment: You do understand that *Path.GetFullPath* returns the **FULL** path so adding it to the end in *fullPath* string is like adding *C:\Program Files......* with *C:\.....* the **FULL** path of the item selected. What you want is **ONLY** *fileName* string

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you want to achieve, but using FileInfo instead of Path.GetFullPath might help.

```
   private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      const string fullPath = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\yeet-n . master\yeet- 
                     master\src\yeet\System\Products\";
      string selection = (string)availableSoftDropBox.SelectedItem;
      var fileInfo = new FileInfo(fullPath + selection);
      string text = fileInfo.FullName;

      if (selection.Equals("Choose Your Own..."))
      {
         if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
         {
            text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
         } 
      } 

      txtFlashFile.Text = text;           
   }
```